# Java error stack trace duplicate after a JsonLayout record

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kubernetes, log4j2

Java app runs in a k8s container and writes log messages to a `stdout` with the next appender:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <JsonLayout compact="true" eventEol="true" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
```

to get collected by `fluentd` and transferred to `ELK`.

I'm not a Java developer, but I wonder if I can somehow get rid of the Java stack trace `Exception in thread "main" ...` in stdout after the normal `log4j2` log record, containing the same message in JSON.

Comment: I think `Exception in thread "main" ...` message comes when a exception is thrown in the application and it was not caught in the application. In such case, application will get stopped. Are you talking about this scenario ? OR can you share more details what you want to remove exactly.

Comment: Yep, I mean the scenario when java process fails on some error and shuts down. In that case it prints a line with an error in JsonLayout and the stack trace right after it.

Comment: Catch the exception and handle it as needed. You would get better suggestions if you provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @D.B. as I said, I'm not a Java developer, so I can't make anything with code by myself, maybe just edit XML or add some code sample by copy-paste. But thank you for a suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try below configuration -

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <JsonLayout compact="true" eventEol="true" includeStacktrace="false" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
```

With `includeStacktrace=false` only the class name and message of the `Throwable` will be logged. Full stacktrace of the exception will not be logged. Check more details [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout)

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, man, but it seems like it would just remove the stacktrace from the json log entry. Also, it doesn't let me use this option: `ERROR JsonLayout contains an invalid element or attribute "includeStacktrace"`

Comment: @cardinal-gray I added details and reference link in above answer. If you are getting error for this attribute, it seems your log4j2 is older version

Comment: You're right, that was on `2.3` log4j version. Nevertheless, it continues printing the full non-JSON stack trace after line with the JSON-formatted error. While the JSON-formatted line doesn't contain full stack trace message (like `at ... (Connection.java:287)`).